# How geometry changes up to Hermitian inner product on Line bundle (Kodaira embedding)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, complex-geometry, deformation-theory, galois-representations

Riemann metric $g \colon= \Sigma g_{ij} dx_i \otimes dx_j$ on a Kähler manifold $M$ will define the length of a line on $M$, i.e. intrinsic geometry. The line bundle $L$ on $M$ is equipped with a Hermitian inner product $<\,\,,\,\,>$, from which the connection $D$ as well as the associated curvature form $\Omega$ is defined. Often for the Kähler metric $\omega(u,v) \colon= g(Ju,v)$, where $d\omega = 0$, Kodaira embedding requires $\omega = \Omega$.

It seems that the geometry of the Riemann manifold $M$ has something to do with not $L$ only but with the Hermitian inner product $<\,\,,\,\,>$ on $L$. However, algebraic geometry simply defines an ample line bundle $L \colon= L(D)$ on a scheme $X$ as $D$ having positive intersection number with all irreducible curve $C$ on $X$. It seems that this property is intrinsic for $D$, i.e. $L$ itself. That is, $L$ is directly connected with the geometry of $X$.

### Q. Why Kodaira embedding requires Hermitian inner product $<\,\,,\,\,>$ on $L$ to equip $L$ the geometry of $M$, i.e., ampleness, whereas algebraic geometry does not?

Comment: Your definition of ample is incorrect.

Comment: A line bundle $L$ on a complex manifold $X$ is positive if it admits an hermitian metric whose curvature form is a positive (hence, Kähler) form. That form has nothing to do with a given Kähler metric on $X$ as you seem to suggest.